# HQL select on embedded map

Tags: hibernate, localization, hql

I want to use (searchable) localization in my models, and i came up with the following model:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    ...
    @ElementCollection
    //key = language code (e.g. 'en') and value = localized label
    private Map<String, String> name;
    ...
}
```

What I want to do no is to query for categories which contain an caseinsensitive needle in a particular localization (e.g. with '%abc%' in their english name)

I tried something like

```
from Category where name.key = :locale and lower(name.value) like :text
```

but that fails with a *cannot dereference scalar collection element* exception.

Now the hibernate docu says, i have to use elements() and indices() for values and keys. For the key this would be easy using `:locale in indices(name)`, but how can i then match a part of the value of this locale in an caseinsensitive manner?

And just in case this is not doable with hql with my model, how else could i model searchable localization?

Comment: Is there a reason why I was downvoted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally came up with the following solution (actually I am pretty sure it would also work using plan maps instead of the embeddable object)

```
@Entity
public class Category {
    ...
    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "locale_category_name", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="id"))
List<Localization> name;
    ...
}

@Embeddable
public class Localization {
    @NotNull
    public String locale;
    @NotNull
    public String label;
}
```

and the query (using join ... with ...)

```
from Category c join c.name l with (l.locale = :locale and lower(l.label) like :text)
```

**Edit:** Actually i was unable to get it to work with a Map, so I am using the @Embeddable solution after all

Comment: actually, i tried it now, and it does not seem to work with Map<String, String> - i always get a cannot defer skalar error. I use use 'key' and 'value' as column names, but probably do not know if that is correct.

Comment: I did some other examples and found out, if I use `Map<String, String>` then my query should be: `from Category c where lower(c.name[:locale]) like :text`