# Hibernate - different tables for each reference point to an entity

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many

I am trying to do localization with hibernate, and since I am stuck with @ElementCollection (see [HQL select on embedded map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14296113/hql-select-on-embedded-map)), I want to try a different approach using real entities:

```
@Entity
public class Category {
  ..
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) 
  @Cascade(...) 
  List<Localization> name;
}

@Entity
public class Localization {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  private long id;
  @NotNull
  public String locale;
  @NotNull
  public String label;
}
```

Now I know this is not very nice since actually it would allow a category to have multiple english translations, but that's fine for me.

**My question:**
Since I will use such localizeable constructs all over my database and there will be quite a lot of localized date, the localization table will grow quite big. Since I want to have an eager fetch on the localized relations, this might become an performance issue.

Is it possible to create a separate table for each ManyToOne mapping (so basically what is done by @ElementCollection implicitly, which I cannot use, see the link above). 
So the result should be many tables with identical structure like:

```
locale_category_name (id : long, locale : string, label : string)
locale_category_description (id : long, locale : string, label : string)
locale_product_name (id : long, locale : string, label : string)
```

etc.